# Java stream API: are there syntax sugar for identity functor?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

We use several `Map` as simple memory DB over list of objects:

```
class Person {
    public String id;
    public String phone;
    public String email;
    // and get/set and other fields...
}

List<Person> persons;
Map<String, Person> emailLookup = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getEmail, p -> p));
Map<String, Person> phoneLookup = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPhone, p -> p));
Map<String, Person> idLookup = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, p -> p));
```

Are there any syntax sugar or built-in functor in Java SE to replace  `p -> p` with something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Function.identity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) but if you want short then I don't think you'll beat your existing `p -> p`.

Comment: I've started to use `__ -> __` syntax to highlight insignificance of variable name. Note that single underscore sign is reserved in Java 8.